# Laurent series for a polynomial in the numerator

Tags: analysis, laurent-series

I have been given the following function for which I am supposed to construct the laurent series around the singular point -1:

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+4z+4}{z+1}$$

From the general formula I know that this implies:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n*(z-(-1))$$

Since we are instructed to only use the geometric series I did the following subsitution:

$$x=z-1 \Rightarrow z=x+1$$

So the function takes the following form:

$$f=\frac{(x+1)^2+4(x+1)+4}{x+2}$$
which can be rewritten as:

$$f=\frac{(x^2+6x+10)}{2}*\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})}$$

then applying the geometric series yields:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}*x^{n+2}+6x^{n+1}+10x^n$$
from this expression one can do the backsubstitution.

Is this in any way the correct approach? I am unsure about the boundedness of the series I found, as far as I understand it, it should hold for $$0<|z|<2$$ and I don't know if I did the subsitution correctly in the first place.

Thanks for any helpful advice or correction!

Comment: To get the LS at $z=a$ you must expand in powers of $z-a$. In your case that means powers of $z+1$. Your attempt uses powers of $z-1$, so is of no help. [You should have taken $x=z+1$. But advice: don't use $x$ for a complex number. we always assume $x$ is the real part of $z$.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for pointing this out! Assuming the substitution-error didn't happen, is this at least generally the right way to construct LS for such functions?

Comment: Why not just do the question as set? It is very hard to comment on an argument based on a false assumption.

Comment: @ancientmathematician okay, when I subsitute x=z+1 i get:

$$\frac{(x-1)^2+4(x-1)+4}{x}$$

To make the geometric series appear I add and subtract 1:

$$f=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{1-(1-x)}$$
which leads to
$$f=x^2+2x+1*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-x)^n$$ and this is where I get stuck, when I substitute with z again it leads to:

$$f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n*z^{n+2}+4z^{n+1}+4z^n$$

And this seems to be a series around the point 0..so where is the issue?

Comment: But you once again have expanded in powers of $z$ and not powers of $z+1$. Look up the definition of "Laurent series at $z_0$".

Answer (score 1):

The function
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)=\frac{z^2+4z+4}{z+1}}
\end{align*}
has a simple pole at $z=-1$ and is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$. A Laurentexpansion at $z=-1$ can be obtained by expanding the numerator of $f$ in terms of $(z+1)$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{z^2+4z+4}{z+1}\\
&=\frac{(z+2)^2}{z+1}=\frac{(1+(z+1))^2}{z+1}\\
&=\frac{1+2(z+1)+(z+1)^2}{z+1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{z+1}+2+(z+1)}
\end{align*}